# tmo nexus 6 update error 5.0.1 to 5.1

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, 5.1-lollipop, nexus-6

I have a tmobile nexus 6 and I received the update yesterday. After downloading and installing, during the install where the robot is on the screen, it says error. Phone reboots and I'm still on 5.0.1. I did this three times yesterday.

I am not rooted and I do not have my bootloader unlocked. I am stock all the way. I bricked too many phones in the past trying to pretend I knew what I was doing.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this without doing a factory reset first?

Comment: Do you have disk encryption enabled?